# Wi-Fi and Bluetooth not working

Tags: wireless, xubuntu, bluetooth

I was using Windows for many years, I have hp 15-bs658tx model laptop with amd radeon graphics.I'm using Ubuntu 19, everything is working fine, but unable to connect Wi-Fi and Bluetooth, its showing no Wi-Fi adapter, and when I'm trying to turn on blutooth on in settings its remaining off.

I'm photographer and editor, so pleases suggest which Linux would be best for me.

My laptop uses realtek8723de driver, but I'm unable to do anything.

Comment: Ubuntu 19?   Ubuntu releases for desktop & servers use a *year.month* format, and only specialist releases use *year* only, and given specialist releases are for devices Xubuntu makes no sense (they don't have keyboards/mouse/displays), plus they only come out on even years (eg. Ubuntu Core 18 for IoT appliances)

Answer (score 1):

Try this driver: [Realtek RTL8723DE module for Linux kernel version >= 5.0](https://github.com/smlinux/rtl8723de)

First, make sure you have the dependencies installed:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install dkms git linux-headers-generic
sudo apt dist-upgrade
```

Reboot to ensure you are using the newest installed kernel.

Then, run the following commands to install the driver:

```
git clone https://github.com/smlinux/rtl8723de.git -b 5.0-up
dkms add ./rtl8723de
dkms install rtl8723de/5.1.1.8_21285.20171026_COEX20170111-1414
depmod -a
reboot
```